# Can I connect iPhone 6 to an old Samsung TV without HDMI?

Tags: iphone, television

it is a macbook 2008 2ghz intel core 2 duo, NVIDIA Geforce 9400m 256mb, software ox10.9.5 (13F34)
serial W8843A9J1AQ

THANKS
ANDREW

[image: and this is the samsung tv]![this is the macbook - thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw3R6.jpg)
I have an iphone 6 and an old macbook - i want to watch movies from these apple products on an 7 year old samsung tv monitor - the tv does not have hdmi but it has the old pc and av connections. Is there a cable I can buy to view items from apple products on the Samsung monitor?? thanks

Comment: Could you give more details about the macbook (a different cable could be needed depending which model it is), and confirm what the "old PC" connection is ([these visuals](http://www.svideo.com/pctvcables.html) should help, if needed). I'd assume that its VGA, but it's better to be sure.

Comment: Many thanks D.G. - i have just added images of the macbook and tv

Comment: What model is the macbook? That looks like a *Mini DisplayPort* but I'd prefer to be sure, and I think some, but not all, models were able to send audio along with the video which could change the cable choices. You should be able to click the Apple logo in the menu, and select "About This Mac" to get more information on the model.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the video cable you need.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DJCBBZE)

[Here's the audio cable you need.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000068O3B)

Based on the presumed age of the laptop, it's a Mini DisplayPort connection, not Thunderbolt.  The former cannot carry audio, hence the second cable.

Comment: It's a safe bet, though some Mini DisplayPort connections do carry audio, apparently. e.g. This [macbook pro](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.53-aluminum-17-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. For your iPhone 6, purchase a Lightning Digital AV Adapter:

   - https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD826AM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter

     And a HDMI to DVI adapter cable:
   - [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01FM51SHG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FM51SHG)

2. For your MacBook, you need to purchase a Mini DP to DVI cable:

   - [https://www.amazon.com/CableCreation-Displayport-Thunderbolt-Compatible-Cable/dp/B01FM51ZTM/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FM51ZTM)